# R function to loop to import and set row header for multiple excel files

Tags: r, readxl

I have 4 excel files I've imported through loop function and I want add a command to make the Nth row the header for each file. The first half of my script works well but nothing happens on the row_to_names() line. I need some help

```
library(janitor)
library(readxl)

#Assigning files df and already assigned directory paths
files  <- c(path19, path20, path21, path22)
label <- c("def19","def20", "def21", "def22")

#Assigning nth row for the header
n=3

for (a in seq_along(files)) {
  assign(label[a], read_xlsx(files[a], sheet = "sheetname"))  %>% 
    row_to_names(n)
  
}
```

Comment: Why not `read_xlsx(files[a], sheet = "sheetname", skip = 2)` to have the 3rd row as headers? What am I missing?

Comment: @RuiBarradas That is option, but I'm anticipating for other future files to have headers on the second or fourth row, not just the 3rd. Thanks for replying

Comment: Is there something, a pattern that tells which is the headers row? That pattern could be before the headers or the headers themselves. If all information comes from the data, then it would be possible to parse the file and find the headers row.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you for your earlier suggestion. I'm going to use that for the time being. Thanks again